# Form does not submit in Angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am new to Angular Programming. If someone can help locating the error.

AddEmployee FORM (HTML)

```
<div ng-controller="EmployeeController">
<form novalidate>
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="Employee.EmployeeName" /><br />
    Salary:<input type="text"  ng-model="Employee.Salary" /><br />
   <select ng-model="Employee.DepartmentId">
    <option value="`enter code here`">--Select --</option>
    <option ng-repeat="d in Department" ng-selected="selectedItemvalue == d.DepartmentId" value="{{d.DepartmentId}}">{{d.DepartmentName}}</option>
</select>
     <button type="submit" ng-click="SaveData(Employee)">Submit</button>

    </form>
```

Employee Contoller

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp",[])
                .controller("EmployeeController", function ($scope, $http) {
                    $scope.Employee = {
                        EmployeeName: '',
                        Salary: '',
                        DepartmentId:''
                    };
                   $scope.SaveData = function (data) {
                       $http({
                            url: 'PostEmployee',
                            method: 'POST',
                            data: JSON.stringify(data),
                            headers: {'content-type':'application/json'}
                        }).success(function (response) {
                            alert('Success');
                        }).error(function (error) {
                            alert('Error');
                        })
                    }

                    $http.get('GetDepartments').then(function (response) {
                        $scope.Department = response.data;
                    });
                });
```

When I click on submit, SaveData method is probably not called. Plase help

UPDATE:

ng-app="MyApp" is added as parameter to body tag in the layout page and all the required scripts too. Moreover, the dropdown list gets populated correctly.

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
@RenderBody()

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

UPDATE 2:
This is how the source looks in the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AddEmployee</title>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">

<div ng-controller="EmployeeController">
<form novalidate name="F1">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="Employee.EmployeeName" /><br />
    Salary:<input type="text"  ng-model="Employee.Salary" /><br />
   <select ng-model="Employee.DepartmentId">
    <option value="">--Select --</option>
    <option ng-repeat="d in Department" ng-selected="selectedItemvalue == d.DepartmentId" value="{{d.DepartmentId}}">{{d.DepartmentName}}</option>
</select>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="SaveData(Employee)">Submit</button>

    </form>

</div>


<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>


<script src="/Scripts/EmployeeController.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Did you call your `controller.js` on your `layout` page?
- Have you checked your controller is initialized?
- **Please define `$scope.Employee ={}` on globally in your controller.**

Comment: '<form novalidate>
        .....
        <input type="button" ng-click="SaveData(Employee)" value="Submit"/>
 </form>'
Did not work. No error on console

Comment: thats not the way, form should be submitted on button of type submit and also ng-submit should work.

Comment: Yup I know. I just suggest to a optional way only.

Comment: If you didn't get any error on console, then it should fire

Comment: And just remove this code `var MyApp =` to assign  angular module to a global variable

Comment: @RameshRajendran remoning  var MyApp =  did not help. No error on console again.  I have replaced <input type="button"> with <button type="submit" ng-click="SaveData(Employee)">Submit</button>

Comment: @RameshRajendran Controller.Js is called on the page. I guess the controller is initialized as the dropdown list gets populated with the department as an effect of 
$http.get('GetDepartments').then(function (response) {
$scope.Department = response.data;
(BTW, I dont know what 'controller is initialized' mean)
Let me know if your question (Have you checked your controller is initialized?) is not answered.

Comment: kindly define `$scope.Employee ={}` on globally in your controller, then let me know it's work or not?

Comment: Okay. Everything is good.  How you know the function is not call? did you check with the breakpoint? or alert()?

Comment: I checked it with alert() :(

Comment: OMG :( . Did you closed your div(all)  tag's correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify an AngularJS module (in your case MyApp) to be used as the root module for the application.

Comment: Just F12 & see the console log.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-app` directive for initialization of angular app. `ng-app="MyApp"` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to metion app name

solution

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <form novalidate class="simple-form">
        <label>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /></label><br />
        <label>E-mail: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" /></label><br />
        Best Editor: <label><input type="radio" ng-model="user.preference" value="vi" />vi</label>
        <label><input type="radio" ng-model="user.preference" value="emacs" />emacs</label><br />
        <input type="button" ng-click="reset()" value="Reset" />
        <input type="submit" ng-click="update(user)" value="Save" />
      </form>
      <pre>user = {{user | json}}</pre>
      <pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
    </div>
    </div>

<script>
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.master = {};

      $scope.update = function(user) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
      };

      $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
      };

      $scope.reset();
    }]);
</script>
```

Refer this https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms